# How can I use tag helpers to get a model property's name on an arbitrary element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

ASP.NET Core.

```
 <label asp-for="FooModelProperty">...</label>
```

This generates a form control with the appropriate property name. Same for select, input, etc.

But I need that name on some random element, e.g. a `div`, so I can use it in JavaScript. And the problem is `asp-for` tag helper doesn't work on an arbitrary element.

So how do I do something like this:

```
<div asp-for="FooModelProperty">...</div>
```

Comment: There is the old school helper of course: `<div data-propname="@Html.NameFor(model => model.FooModelProperty)">...</div>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ModelExpression` class was created to help with cases like these. You can add it as a property to your TagHelper and access the property name from there.

Here's an example:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("*", Attributes = forName)]
public class NameAppenderTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string forName = "na-for";

    [HtmlAttributeName(forName)]
    public ModelExpression PropertyName { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // add the property name as an attribute to the element
        output.Attributes.Add("data-property-name", PropertyName.Name);

        // if you'd like the [Display] name value, you can use this:
        // output.Attributes.Add("data-property-name", PropertyName.Metadata.DisplayName);
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

When used in Razor like this:

```
<div na-for="MyProperty"></div>
```

It will output:

```
<div data-property-name="MyProperty"></div>
```